# Remove container Log Docker after one month

Tags: image, docker, containers

I have a series of containers and they produce logs regularly. I want to compress it every day and after a month it will be removed automatically.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

This task cannot be done via default docker/docker-compose functions.
Try this logrotate config:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
  rotate 31
  daily
  compress
  missingok
  delaycompress
  copytruncate
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Put the code in the original Docker configuration?

Comment: @MohammadGolmohammadi no, you need create the file `/etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs` and running test `logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs`

Comment: say : No such file or directory